# incorrect synatax near '>'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
select (round(
   (isnull(sum(OD1.AfterDiscount),0)
    + isnull((select sum(td.freight) from K_FS_GenerateDcno TD where TD.Name =32),0) 
    - isnull((select sum(recamount) from   K_FS_AmountReceived AR where  AR.Name=32),0)
   )>500000,0))
from  K_FS_OrderDetails OD 
left outer join K_FS_OrderDetails1 OD1 on OD1.ID=OD.sno
left outer  join K_FS_DistributorDetails DD on DD.sno = OD.customername
where OD.confirmation='True' and OD.customername=32
```

I am getting an error at > 500000 condition...

please help me

Comment: You have an extra closing paren after the `,0)`.  There has got to be a clearer way to express this logic.

Comment: Errors like this are a *lot* easier to notice if you format your code to be human-readable.

Comment: Do you need `> 500000` on another level/location in your query? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Round amount should be less than 500000

Comment: What is the error you get? Are you sure the two sub-select statements always return a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
        Select    a.*
        From (
             select round(
             ( 
                 isnull(sum(OD1.AfterDiscount),0)+   
                  isnull((select sum(td.freight) from K_FS_GenerateDcno TD where TD.Name =32),0)  -  
                  isnull((select sum(recamount) from   K_FS_AmountReceived AR where AR.Name=32),0)
            ),0)   as RoundedAmount
            from  K_FS_OrderDetails OD 
            left outer join K_FS_OrderDetails1 OD1 on OD1.ID=OD.sno
            left outer  join K_FS_DistributorDetails DD on DD.sno = OD.customername
            where OD.confirmation='True' and OD.customername=32 
        )   as a
        Where RoundedAmount > 500000
```

This will evaluate `RoundedAmount` after the calculations..

Answer (score 0):

some parentheses are wrong but there is no information what you want to do with the query.

the simplified structure of your select part is:

```
(round( (isnull()+isnull()-isnull()) > 50000,0))
```

so you are rounding a boolean value ?!